# Why Apexchart's inner label is overflowing

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

As you can see in the picture i have a donut chart with apex with  that long favorite genre value [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfqSG.png). but it is overflowing on the chart because of its size (probably bc its width is as long as the outter chart?). Doing some research about it, I found out the only interface it provides is the font-size and font family and not the width. I thought maybe reducing the width could fix the issue but since the element being used in the chart is <Text>, it doesn't support such a thing!

```
  .apexcharts-datalabels-group {
    width: 1rem !important;
  }
```

alternatively tried pass the width to the options, but again no results:

```
plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            donut: {
              labels: {
                show: true,
                name: {
                  show: true,
                },
                value: {
                  show: true,
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: "0.9rem",
                  width: "2rem",
                  
                  style: {
                    width: "2rem",
                  },
                },
```

how can I make this long genre fit in the circle nicely without the need to reduce the font-size ? because the value is dynamic and the only long one is this one.

here is the whole component with options:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (genresCount && chartRef.current) {
      const options = {
        chart: {
          type: "donut",
          width: 450,
          height: 400,
          fontFamily: "poppins, Arial, sans-serif",
          animations: {
            enabled: true,
            easing: "easeinout",
            speed: 1350,

            animateGradually: {
              enabled: true,
            },
            dynamicAnimation: {
              enabled: true,
              speed: 1350,
            },
          },
        },
        series: Object.values(genresCount),
        labels: Object.keys(genresCount),
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },

        noData: {
          text: "There is no book in your shelf.",
          align: "center",
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          style: {
            color: "#1D1D1D",
            fontSize: "0.875rem",
            fontFamily: "poppins",
          },
        },
        stroke: {
          show: false,
        },
        colors: ["#6936F5", "#853333", "#F2831B", "#B2B7C5", "#578C7A"],
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            donut: {
              labels: {
                show: true,
                name: {
                  show: true,
                },
                value: {
                  show: true,
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: "0.9rem",
                },
                total: {
                  cssClass: "favorite-genre__center-heading",
                  show: true,
                  showAlways: true,
                  label: "Favorite genre",
                  fontSize: "0.8rem",
                  formatter: function (w) {
                    const maxPercentage = Math.max(...w.globals.series);
                    const index = w.globals.series.indexOf(maxPercentage);
                    return w.globals.labels[index];
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };

      const chart = new ApexCharts(chartRef.current, options);
      chart.render();
      return () => {
        chart.destroy();
      };
    }
  }, [genresCount]);

  if (!genresCount) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <motion.section
      className="genres-piechart"
      initial="initial"
      animate="in"
      exit="out"
      variants={fadeInVariant}
      transition={{ duration: 0.7, delay: 0.7 }}
    >
      <div ref={chartRef}></div>
    </motion.section>
  );
```

thanks !

tried large number of css property to alter the size but it seems not to be a regular text